# Swiffy flash file prevents scrolling on browser

Tags: flash, mobile, scroll, desktop, google-swiffy

Scratch that, it happens on desktop browsers as well.
I've converted a 300x250 sized banner and once it loads, it removes the sidebar.

You can see that directly here: http://dev.eonlinelatinola.com/

---

I've recently exported a Flash 8 file to Swiffy. Then I uploaded it to DFP and tried to serve it on our mobile site.
I've noticed that the when the creative loads, it prevents me from scrolling further on the page.

Here's a preview of said creative on our mobile site:

http://pubads.g.doubleclick.net/gampad/preview_cookie?gct=8NDhcVcJW84Y7-LjrQUw7_6YtQWIAYCAgKDTo8ukaA&op=set&redirect=http://la.eonline.com/mexico&redirect_hash=AJlzBa2BY0eQPLKa0UliOtEQnfQWmrXm4Q&lineItemId=92998767&creativeId=64662001287

(access it through mobile, but be aware the site is geotergetted: choose Mexico as your country on the dropdown menu at the bottom. thanks)

What could be causing this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

We've narrowed down the problem to swiffy setting overflow:hidden on the <body> tag but cannot figure out why it's doing it.

For now the workaround seems to be to put:

```
body { overflow: visible !important; }
```

Somewhere on the page.